# Starting with RSpec -- <top (required)>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I just started with RSpec. I am following Code School's lessons here: http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1

I am using Cloud 9 to save all the files and run Ruby.

This is my directory structure:

[image]

This is my code for zombie.rb:

```
class Zombie
end
```

This is my code for zombie_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "zombie"
```

This is my result:

```
rspec_example/spec $ ruby zombie_spec.rb 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-        2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require':     cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from zombie_spec.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

When I try to change the require path inside of zombie_spec.rb:

```
require "./spec_helper"
require "zombie"
```

I get this:

```
    rspec_example/spec $ ruby zombie_spec.rb 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/rspec_example/spec/spec_helper.rb:19:in `<top     (required)>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from zombie_spec.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

If I change the spec again to this:

```
require "./spec_helper"
require "../zombie"
```

And I get this:

```
    rspec_example/spec $ ruby zombie_spec.rb 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/rspec_example/spec/spec_helper.rb:19:in `<top     (required)>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from zombie_spec.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

And this is everything from the spec_helper.rb file the error message referenced:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # This setting enables warnings. It's recommended, but in some cases may
  # be too noisy due to issues in dependencies.
  config.warnings = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

Comment: Don't you want to run `rspec zombie_spec.rb` (instead of `ruby zombie_spec.rb `)?

Comment: I think the `uninitialized constant RSpec` error indicates that Rspec was not loaded properly. Try adding `require 'rspec/core'` to the top of you `spec_helper`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: you don't run the xxx_spec.rb file through ruby, you run it through rspec. I see that orde beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

dude, u want to run RSpec and you are using a ruby command 
make sure you run RSpec like this.

```
rspec  spec/zombie_spec.rb
```